# How to clean gunked up sandpaper?

Tags: sanding, hardwood-refinishing, sander

How do I remove gunk buildup on sandpaper?

After using acetone to remove some of the finish I am using sandpaper on the door. The sandpaper keeps getting black goo on it. But the sandpaper underneath seems to be perfectly fine.

Is there a way to remove the goo and save the sandpaper? Would a sandpaper saver block work something like this: [image]

Comment: In my opinion, if there is still any finish, you haven't reached the sand paper stage. I prefer mechanical removal, then chemical in limited application, and finally when I am at wood, I switch to paper. https://youtu.be/lljxPNiRKsA

Comment: I've heard the bottom of your shoe will work as well or an old shoe.  I find it does remove some of the gunk.  Hadn't heard of this sand paper saver block.

Comment: @bishop I tried your approach, and it worked amazingly! I really appreciate the idea.

Comment: Awesome, @Whitecat, glad it worked!